# How to clone/make another copy of an deployed bot on Azure?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, clone

I want to create a copy of an existing bot deployed on Azure. So, that the new copy can be used to create a new bot with minor changes. 
Wanted to know if there is any direct option on Azure portal itself to create the clone of the existing bot

Comment: Are you referring to continuous deployment?

Comment: "with minor changes": can you define what kind of "minor changes" you have in mind? It will also depend on how the initial bot was created

Comment: As @Nicolas R can you provide more information You may also refer to the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cnewrg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Export Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/export-template-portal) functionality to export the existing bot and any other associated resources from Azure, then use the [Template deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal#deploy-resources-from-custom-template) function to deploy your custom template.

Comment: Thanks for the response but getting
Bot Services cannot be exported yet and is not included in the template. error details.

{"code":"ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors","message":"Export template operation completed with errors. Some resources were not exported. Please see details for more information.","details":[{"code":"ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound","target":"Microsoft.BotService/botServices","message":"The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template."}]}

Comment: You might be able to manually add in the template JSON for the botService using [this schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.botservice/2017-12-01/botservices). You’ll have to fill out all the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

As the bot channels registration isn't currently supported for template export (as you have found), the best option might be to script something. You can build a bot and have it zipped up and then use cli/powershell to create the needed resources and have it deployed. You can script creating new apps and bot channel resources fairly easy.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg) for more info on how to generally go about that. Let me know if you want a sudo sample.